# ¿Cómo puedo colorear filas impares en una consulta sql desde php?

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo el siguiente código, el cual muestra los registros de una tabla en orden según ID:

```
 <?php
     if(isset($_GET['action']) == 'delete'){
        $id_delete = intval($_GET['id']);
        $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM 1_registros WHERE id='$id_delete' ORDER BY id DESC");
        if(mysqli_num_rows($query) == 0){
            echo '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>No se encontraron datos.</div>';
        }else{
            $delete = mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM 1_registros WHERE id='$id_delete'");
            if($delete){
                echo '<div class="alert alert-primary alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>Los datos han sido eliminados correctamente.</div>';
            }else{
                echo '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>Error, no se pudo eliminar los datos.</div>';
            }
        }
    }
?>
<hr>
<table id="lookup" class="table table-bordered table-hover">  
    <thead bgcolor="#eeeeee" align="center">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Correo</th>
            <th>Texto</th>
            <th>Creado el</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que la fila completa del 2do, 4to, 6to, etc, registro sea de un color distinto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se puede hacer solamente con CSS. Si tiene que ser obligatoriamente en PHP, lo de @Vick Muñoz te debería servir.

Se puede hacer solamente con CSS.

```
#lookup tbody th:nth-child(odd) {
  //CSS para las filas impares
}

#lookup tbody th:nth-child(even) {
  //CSS para las filas pares
}
```

Fuente: [nth-child en mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

Comment: Tal cual. Finalmente me resultó solo con CSS. Gracias.

Comment: Si mal no me equivoco usas Bootstrap... fijate en la documentación la clase `table-striped`creo que era esa. Hace justamente lo que necesitas para las tablas y te vas a ahorrar repetir código CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que tus id son el array que creo, utilizamos el operador **%** para sacar el resto de la división de los números del array entre 2, si es **0** entonces el número es par, si no es igual a 0 entonces es impar, entonces lo imprimo en el atributo *class* y le doy estilo un `background-color` para colorear las celdas, espero te funcione, cualquier duda, hazla saber.

```html
<?php
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);

$cuenta = count($array)-1;

 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
<style>
  
.par{

background-color: #6FA7C1;

}

.impar{

background-color: #8FD6A0;


}

 </style>
</head>

<body >



<table id="lookup" class="table table-bordered table-hover">  
                                   <thead bgcolor="#eeeeee" align="center">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>ID</th>
                                    <th>Nombre</th>
                                    <th>Correo</th>
                                    <th>Texto</th>
                                    <th>Creado el</th>

                                   </tr>
                                  </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                   <?php
                                   $i = 0; 
                                   while($i <= $cuenta): ?>
                                   <tr>
                                    <td class="<?php if($array[$i] %2 ==0){

                                 $par_impar = 'par';

                                 echo $par_impar;
                                }else{
                                 echo $par_impar = 'impar';
                               } ?>"><?php echo $array[$i]; 

                                 $i++; ?></td>
                                 <td class="<?php echo $par_impar; ?>">sdfsdf</td>
                                 <td class="<?php echo $par_impar; ?>">ffffff</td>

                                   </tr>
                                   
                                   <?php  
                                 endwhile; ?>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
```