# ¿Cómo coloreo las filas impares en una tabla php mysql?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo una tabla en `html` que obtiene datos desde `mysql`:

```
<body>
    <div class="container" style=" width:900px">  
        <br />  
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <br />
            <div id="employee_table">
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <tr>
                        <th width="15%">Nombre</th>  
                        <th width="10%">Correo</th>  
                        <th width="30%">Texto</th>  
                        <th width="10%">Creado el</th>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                        {
                    ?>
                        <tr>
                           <td><?php echo $row["nombre"]; ?></td>
                           <td><?php echo $row["correo"]; ?></td>
                           <td><?php echo $row["texto"]; ?></td>
                           <td><?php echo $row["registrado"]; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php
                        }
                    ?>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</body>
```

Lo que quiero, y no logro hacer, es colorear las filas pero solo las que son impares, ya que quiero implementar un sistema tipo: pregunta-respuesta.

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Comment: La forma más simple que me viene a la cabeza es que le pongas un class a las filas impares y le des estilo css a ese class. Habrá más formas de solucionarlo pero pa tu caso que es una tabla pequeña mejor hacerlo de ésta manera. Espero que te sirva :D

Comment: Puedes hacerlo a mano, como ya se indica en la respuesta dada, o implementar una librería de estilos. Por ejemplo [Bulma](https://bulma.io/documentation/elements/table/) es una librería minimalista, con que pongas a tu tabla: `<table class="table is-striped">` ya te lo hace sola. El archivo de Bulma pesa solamente 416 Kb.

Comment: La misma pregunta la hiciste el día de ayer. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/254789/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-colorear-filas-impares-en-una-consulta-sql-desde-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo más rápido y flexible es mediante CSS, usando el modificador [`nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
p:nth-child(odd) {
  background: red;
}

p:nth-child(even) {
  background: blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>The first paragraph.</p>
<p>The second paragraph.</p>
<p>The third paragraph.</p>

<p><b>Note:</b> Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions do not support the :nth-child() selector.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Fuente: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_nth-child_odd_even

En tu código quedaría algo como:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: red;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tr>
                    <th width="15%">Nombre</th>  
                    <th width="10%">Correo</th>  
                    <th width="30%">Texto</th>  
                    <th width="10%">Creado el</th>
                </tr>
                    <tr>
                       <td>aaa</td>
                       <td>bbb</td>
                       <td>ccc</td>
                       <td>ddd</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                       <td>aaa</td>
                       <td>bbb</td>
                       <td>ccc</td>
                       <td>ddd</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                       <td>aaa</td>
                       <td>bbb</td>
                       <td>ccc</td>
                       <td>ddd</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                       <td>aaa</td>
                       <td>bbb</td>
                       <td>ccc</td>
                       <td>ddd</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                       <td>aaa</td>
                       <td>bbb</td>
                       <td>ccc</td>
                       <td>ddd</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                       <td>aaa</td>
                       <td>bbb</td>
                       <td>ccc</td>
                       <td>ddd</td>
                    </tr>
            </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No pensé que era tan simple. Me sirvió perfecto. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Debería ser algo como el `if` que puse dentro del while usando `MOD`.

```
  <body>
        <div class="container" style=" width:900px">  
            <br />  
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <br />
                <div id="employee_table">
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <tr>
                            <th width="15%">Nombre</th>  
                            <th width="10%">Correo</th>  
                            <th width="30%">Texto</th>  
                            <th width="10%">Creado el</th>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                            $x = 0;
                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                            {
                        ?>
                            <?php 
                              if($x%2 == 0){
                                  echo "<tr style='background-color:#0f0' > Par </tr>";
                            }else{
                                  echo "<tr style='background-color:#00f' > Impar </tr>";
                                }

                            $x = $x + 1;

                            ?>
                        <?php
                           }
                        ?>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </body>
```

a modo de ejemplo imprimo  PAR O IMPAR, ahí deberías poner tus columnas y aplicar el style al TD

Answer (score 1):

```css
tbody tr:nth-child(odd){
  background-color: #4C8BF5;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Cabecera 1</th>
      <th>Cabecera 2</th>
      <th>Cabecera 3</th>
      <th>Cabecera 4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>16</td>
      <td>17</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>21</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Podrías solucionarlo a través de CSS con la pseudo-clase `nth-child(odd)` para los elementos impares. Podrías darle otro estilo a las pares usando `nth-child(even)`.

Comment: pero tu solución también afectaría con un color de estilo la línea del encabezado es decir de los títulos de columna, eso es correcto?

Comment: @anonimo No, porque si te fijas se aplica los tr que sean hijos del tbody. Los encabezados de las tablas están en el thead.

Comment: @anonimo Añadí cabeceras a la tabla para que se vea mejor su funcionamiento.

Comment: exacto, gracias por la actualización así se comprende mejor